# Do I need to use ST_SetSRID, or does ST_MakePoint()::geography work?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600896/2265468), the way to convert a lat/long to a geography type is

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat), 4326)::geography
```

but so far I've just been using `ST_MakePoint(long, lat)::geography` and it seems to work fine. My queries include checks for

```
ST_Covers(shape, ST_MakePoint(long, lat)::geography)
```

and I haven't seen that give an incorrect answer. But that doesn't mean it's always going to work.

The `shape` column is defined as

```
shape geography(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326)
```

so I thought maybe having the SRID in the column definition was doing the same work as `ST_SetSRID`. But I really don't know.

Probably not relevant, but just in case: the data comes from Natural Earth's [countries data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/), converted to SQL with

```
shp2pgsql -GD ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp table_name
```

That creates a table with a `geog` column also defined as `geography(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326)`, and I've copied some of the data from that into the table with `shape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, somehow for convenience I guess. The cast implicitly assumes your geometries are in EPSG:4326; explicitly setting the original CRS **and** transforming is absolutely necessary when the CRS differ from WGS84. Keep in mind, though, that your *geometries* are not automatically referenced with a CRS, so by doing so on creation or generation you'll be on safer grounds.
As an addition:
If you define your column definition with SRID (which you should), e.g. in the process of creating an empty table, all inserts into that column will be assumed (!) to match that SRID and get assigned the identifier. As with the function though, PostGIS doesn´t care if they don´t match!
Pretty much the same applies if your table was created by script, with SRID definition, and you add geometries to the column later.
<s>I´m curious though as to why *shp2pgsql* creates *geography* type if not explicitly specified...</s>  Didn't see the flag...

Comment: So to clarify: as a special case, when a geometry hasn't had an SRID set, then casting it to geography implicitly assumes 4326; so that `MakePoint()::geography` approach does the same thing as `SetSrid(MakePoint(), 4326)::geography`? But if my lat/long weren't in 4326, or if I wanted something other than 4326, I'd need to be explicit.

Comment: "I´m curious though as to why shp2pgsql creates geography type if not explicitly specified..." - by default it creates a geometry, the -G option tells it to use geography.

Comment: @philh ah yeah. I just haven't seen it there. was it there before?...you tricked me! ,) but, you clarified correctly. (best thing I could come up with right now as to why it does essentially the same, is a discussuon in a [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/265) about possible auto-transformation during casting, from 8 years ago, and with a following commit to tighten the *geography* cast to allow only *unknown* or *4326* SRIDs)